# Spring @Autowired not working in my new class but works in HomeController

Tags: java, spring

I'm reasonably green when it comes to Spring.

I get this message when trying to auto wire the following together and I have not yet been able to solve it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit h name 'authenticator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested excep tion is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autow ire method: public void nz.co.myproject.auth.Authenticator.setAuthenticationManag er(org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager); nested ex ception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No m atching bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.Authentication Manager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autow ire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**Spring configuration**

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
    <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="nz.co.myproject.auth.MyUserDetailsService" />

<beans:bean id="authenticator" class="nz.co.myproject.auth.Authenticator"/>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

**My class**

```
@Component
public class Authenticator {

        /* Authentication manager does not inject successfully, instead gives error message */
        @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) { 
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

**What does work**

What is interesting is that I only get this when trying to inject the authentication manager into the Authenticator. When I try and inject the authentication manager into HomeController, the dependency injects successfully.

For example, the following works:

**Spring configuration**

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="nz.co.myproject.auth.MyUserDetailsService" />

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

**My class**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /* authentication manager injects successfully */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; 

       ......

}
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

**Full context configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="nz.co.myproject.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="nz.co.myproject.auth" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- We want to use spring's multipart resolver -->
    <beans:bean  id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- 10MB hard limit. Lower values can be handled by the servlets, but over 10MB is suspicious.-->
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10485760"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <!--  Internationalisation -->

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="interceptors">
            <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--  Email Messaging -->
    <beans:bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <beans:property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="*******"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="*******"/>
        <beans:property name="port" value="587"/>

        <beans:property name="javaMailProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- this is a template message that we can pre-load with default state -->
    <beans:bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <beans:property name="from" value="noreply@myproject.co.nz" />
        <beans:property name="subject" value="Your order" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="smtpMailer" class="nz.co.myproject.messaging.smtp.SMTPMailer">
        <beans:property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <beans:property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**Full Security Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <debug />

    <http auto-config="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/myproject" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcL---4xQYA" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="nz.co.myproject.auth.myUserDetailsService" />

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: dude check out the first line in your both spring configs, id for authenticationManager is missing. And why are you creating a bean of authenticator class when it is already annotated with component ?

Comment: Have you tried mvoing the autowired and qualifier annotations to the setter method instead of the field?  The exception message makes it sound as though Spring is trying to use setter injection and then is not seeing the qualifier annotation.  Also, if youare declaring the bean in the context file, then you don't need to add the @Component annotation.

Comment: Hi Sikorski - you're right, but that's not the solution :(

Comment: rees, I did try that. I did not make a difference. One thing I should note is that I am using Spring Security and AuthenticationManager is a component of Spring Security. I understand the same as you, that Spring is trying to use setter injection and not seeing the qualifier annotation, but, it does see it in HomeController

Comment: Please post your full context configuration, `component-scan` and all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no bean named `authenticationManager` in your bean definition XML. 
Second bean defintion example work as you put `id="authenticationManager"` into it. So you created bean with id:authenticationManager

Comment: Sorry that was misleading. Second example also works without id and the first (not working) example does not work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think multiple `component scan` tags works.

Change:

`<context:component-scan base-package="nz.co.myproject.controller" />`
`<context:component-scan base-package="nz.co.myproject.auth" />`

To:

`<context:component-scan base-package="nz.co.myproject" />`

That will look for all `@Component`, `@Controller`, etc. annotations in all sub-packages of `nz.co.myproject`, and enable them for autowiring.

Comment: Because of the exception message, I think it is more like what rees said. Spring is trying to use setter injection (i.e. it can see the component) and then is not seeing the qualifier annotation.